# How to launch `.desktop` files from the terminal (or dmenu)

Tags: .desktop

I want to run `.desktop` files from the terminal and dmenu. From the terminal, it should ideally be run with `./app.desktop` or `/path/to/app.desktop`, and `app.desktop` would be put in a `$PATH` directory. I'd rather not have to use an external command like `gtk-launch app.desktop`.

Additionally, I've found that `gtk-launch` doesn't always work to launch the application with `gtk-launch app.desktop`, and even when it does work, putting `#!/path/to/gtk-launch` at the top   of the `.desktop` returns the error `gtk-launch: no such application ./app.desktop` when I run `./app.desktop` with it executable.

I'm using bspwm and generally prefer launching things from the terminal or with `dmenu_run` so I don't have a desktop from which I can click on the `.desktop` files to launch them.

How can I make the `.desktop` files executable?

Answer (score 4):

Per https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/1002900 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/54#note_1755632,

```
gio launch /path/file.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided that they are executable (`chmod u+x /path/to/app.desktop`) you can add this shebang at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

And from then on you can call your application with:

```
/path/to/app.desktop
```

For example, this .desktop file will start `xeyes`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xeyes
Exec=xeyes
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Comment: When I use `xdg-open app.desktop`, it doesn't run the `Exec=` line but instead runs `$EDITOR app.desktop` which opens the `.desktop` file for editing in nvim for me without `perl-file-mimeinfo` installed (I'm on Manjaro).  With `perl-file-mimeinfo`, it opens the `path/to/app,desktop` in my browser, which then prompts me to download the file. How should I configure `xdg-open` to correctly open the application?

Comment: Can you post the app.desktop file? Because I tried this and it works flawlessly. There might be an issue with the .desktop file itself. I added a minimum example.

Comment: I can only confirm what ChocolateOverflow wrote: xdg-open does not "launch" files of `content-type: application/x-desktop` but tries to _edit_ them.
For confirmation I tested with the example from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the file, and executing whatever the `Exec=` line says should be executed. This should do it:

```
$(awk '/^Exec=/{sub(/^Exec=/, ""); print}' file.desktop)
```

Whatever was in `file.desktop` will launch.

You could also expand this and make a script that takes an argument APP and runs that command on the `file.desktop` file(s) that have "Name=APP" in it(them).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gtk-launch` installed, you can run:

```
gtk-launch example.desktop
```