Is `xdg-open`, `gtk-launch`, or `gio-launch` preferable for invoking `.desktop` files via the CLI?
Question

I've looked through their documentation, but I've not located any significant differences. Since their sources are fairly unintelligible to me, does anyone know of a reason to choose one over the other? I ask because I ultimately have to choose one when invoking a .desktop file from the shell.
Examples

An old answer of mine which collated information from technical discussions about gtk-open's inability to invoke .desktop files appears to prefer gio-launch, whereas another appears to prefer gtk-launch, presumably merely because its man documentation explicitly mentions its purpose being so.
Rationale

xdg-open doesn't execute .desktop files due to a long-unremediated bug. The cited binaries are the sole alternative options that I know of which come with all standard distributions.

I would recommend xdg-open; this is a shell script that will try and work out the current desktop environment and use the appropriate command, which may include testing multiple alternatives (eg gio then gvfs-open then gnome-open).
This should work under multiple desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, LXDE, Enlightenment, Mate...) whereas Gnome-specific commands may not exist.
On a clean Debian 12 install I successfully opened  discord via xdg-open $HOME/Desktop/discord.desktop which was a "Link" file
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Discord
Icon=discord
URL=/usr/share/applications/discord.desktop

I also was successful with the original file xdg-open /usr/share/applications/discord.desktop which was a Application file
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Discord
StartupWMClass=discord
Comment=All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers that's free, secure, and works on both your desktop and phone.
GenericName=Internet Messenger
Exec=/usr/share/discord/Discord
Icon=discord
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
Path=/usr/bin


You've evidently not tried xdg-open nor read the cited threads, because that binary doesn't execute .desktop files. It erroneously invokes them in an editor. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020106/hashbang-for-gnome-desktop-files/32163349#comment19823640_6022017 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626648/how-to-launch-desktop-files-from-the-terminal-or-dmenu/747300#comment1424701_626656.) However, I should have explained this clearly in the question. I'll do so.

I tested it before I posted.  On my debian-12 machine it correctly opens the binary defined in the desktop file; eg [Desktop Entry] Type=Link Name=Discord Icon=discord URL=/usr/share/applications/discord.desktop  worked just fine.

Apologies then, Stephen. That's very different to my experience, since per https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/54#note_1755598, this hasn't worked for many years across many distributions for me and others. Since https://together.jolla.com/question/201843/3028-xdg-open-desktop-dont-open-application-anymore/?answer=201884#post-id-201884:~:text=This%20was%20changed%20on%20purpose explicitly explains that this inability is deliberate, might your package selection be significantly outdated?

Debian 12 is the latest version and this is a new build machine, so no legacy from upgrades (I built this last week to replace an older machine so it hasn't had time to build up cruft yet... give it a year heheheheh).  Note xdg-open is not a GNOME utilitiy and it has special handling for desktop files so even if dio breaks it doesn't mean xdg-open wiill break.

Interesting - thanks. I've not tried Debian, but if I do and xdg-open works there, I'll consider opening a bug report somewhere that affects both Fedora Rawhide and OSTW, and I'll include the information in my answer here. If you specify that your answer applies to Debian, I'll mark it as the accepted one until I test Debian myself.

Answer updated with details of my testing.

@Peilonrayz; For the first, Running gio info "/home/sweh/Desktop/discord.desktop" application/x-desktop  and no output for the second (in debug mode it lists 20 locations that it checks)

Selected DE lxde (I'm using LXDE on Debian 12) and then the discord app opens

Thank you for the help. Unfortunately I can't get xdg-open to launch .desktop files. Originally xdg-mime query filetype $path would result in text/plain; installing perl-file-mimeinfo and using env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE (uses gio) both result in application/x-desktop. I uninstalled all recommended programs resulting from gio mime application/x-desktop. However xdg-open just uses the registered programs which don't have the mimetype specified in the .desktop or mimeapps.list. I give up, and I'm just going to use gio launch. Again thanks for the help.

Very comprehensive and helpful answer, thank you very much.

Options


xdg-open "$path"

For me, the standard xdg-open abstraction doesn't execute the file (presumably by design). Instead, it invokes the file in the associated application for its MIME type.
The sole information I know of which contradicts this is another answer which states that xdg-open executes .desktop files on Debian 12, which is not an OS that I have evaluated (see undermentioned).
Of the lower-level alternatives:

gtk-launch "$path"

Although gtk-launch works for .desktop files inside /usr/share/applications/:

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> gtk-launch 'org.kde.drkonqi.desktop'
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> ^Cg.kde.drkonqi: Invalid pid specified
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart>


...it isn't particularly versatile, because it can't execute anything outside there, or even a .desktop file inside there from its full path:

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> gtk-launch '/usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop'
gtk-launch: no such application /usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop


...as this Bugzilla comment explains (paraphrased):

gtk-launch is nice, but far from enough: according https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-launch.html, it only launches .desktop files residing in /usr/share/application.
It can't be used for launching desktop files from the $XDG_DATA_DIRS list or $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications dir, or $HOME/Desktop, let alone .desktop files from arbitrary paths in the filesystem.


gio launch "$path"

This appears to function as expected - it executes the .desktop file as Dolphin does, rather than attempt to invoke it in the MIME-type's associated application.

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> gio launch '/usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop'
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> org.kde.drkonqi: Invalid pid specified
PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> ^C




Environment


File


It's executable:

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> find /usr/share/applications/ -executable -type f     
/usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop



It's UTF-8:

PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> file '/usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop'
/usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop: KDE config file, Unicode text, UTF-8 text





Operating System

Tested on:

cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20230525
cpe:/o:fedora:40




gtk-launch uses the name of the .desktop file, not the path. From the manpage: "gtk-launch takes at least one argument, the name of the application to launch. The name should match application desktop file name, as residing in /usr/share/application, with or without the '.desktop' suffix." and from gtk-launch --help: "Launch an application (specified by its desktop file name)", so for /usr/share/applications/org.kde.drkonqi.desktop, you need to do gtk-launch org.kde.drkonqi.

But despite that comment in the bug report, it does execute desktop files in $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications (well, at least ~/.local/share/applications) for me in Arch Linux (gtk-launch 3.24.43)

Thanks, @muru. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782676/is-xdg-open-gtk-launch-or-gio-launch-preferable-for-invoking-desktop/782686#comment1498815_782686 has been remediated in revision 5, and I'll test https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782676/is-xdg-open-gtk-launch-or-gio-launch-preferable-for-invoking-desktop/782686#comment1498816_782686 and include that information if I can reproduce it.
